# How To Build Java Native Executable Files For Linux

Tags: java, linux, maven, javafx, build

I'm looking for a way to build my Java or JavaFx apps so that I have a single executable file that runs without installing a Java runtime on the target system that is running Linux (like a .exe on Windows)

Usually, Java apps are packaged into jar files that can be run like this

```sh
java -jar <file-name>.jar
```

This requires us to install a Java JRE beforehand.

I'm looking for a solution to package my Java app so that it can execute without needing a Java JRE on the target machine.

Comment: Assuming you're using Java 14+: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/jpackage/packaging-overview.html#GUID-C1027043-587D-418D-8188-EF8F44A4C06A

Comment: Have you looked at GraalVM? https://www.graalvm.org/docs/introduction/

Comment: @KevinHooke Yes and it was so usefull, considering they introduced them selves as "GraalVM is a high-performance runtime that provides significant improvements in application performance and efficiency which is ideal for microservices" I'm gonna try it in my micro-service projects. but for now I'm sticking to the java solution which is more of a official solution for java. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Slaw mentioned in a comment
for java 14+ [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/jpackage/packaging-overview.html#GUID-C1027043-587D-418D-8188-EF8F44A4C06A) is the best solution

it uses the `jlink` command internally
and supports Mac, Windows, and Linux

---

The official Java-based solution is mentioned above
but its **highly** recommended to use  [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/docs/introduction/)
in case you want extra performance and a better approach for microservices

installation steps are mentioned below in @Kevin Hooke's answer

---

I think ```jlink``` is useable with older Java versions too

*if anyone has experience with `jlink` on older versions please comment below*

Comment: The jlink tool was introcuded with the java module system, so it runs on older Java versions too if they are based on JPMS. The jpackage tool however was introduced with Java 14, so this is not available on older versions but the tool from Java 14 or above can be used to also package older Java versions (but why should one do that).

Answer (score 1):

You can use GraalVM to compile Java apps to native platform executables.

First install GraalVM following steps here: https://www.graalvm.org/docs/getting-started/#install-graalvm

Install the native-image plugin:
`gu install native-image`

Compile your Java app with javac as normal:
`javac YourApp.java`

Compile to a native executable:
`native-image YourApp`

Execute your native executable:
`./YourApp`